# Use Case to Convert Date to Text to display Null

Tags: sql, where-clause

First I am a SQL baby so please be patient with me.  I am trying to query a table with discharge dates in the table. I want to display records where Discharge Reason or date is null.  When I write the query I tried both a case statement and where statement to identify any cases.  I get no results when I run the query.

/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT [EOCKey]

```
-- ,[Division Code]
-- ,[Division]
,[FacilityOrgKey]
,[Facility Code]
,[Facility Name]
,[DMH ID]
,[Consumer Full Name]
,[Open Admission]
--,[ProviderSiteOrgKey]
--,[Provider Site]
,[Local Chart Number]
--,[Initial Contact Date]
,[Admission Date]
,[Admission Reason Code]
--  ,[Admission Reason]
,[Admission Comment]
--  ,[Referral Source Code]
,[Referral Source]
--  ,[ReferralOfficeOrgKey]
--  ,[Referral Office]
,[Discharge Date]
,[Discharge Reason Code]
,[Discharge Reason]
,[Discharge Comment]
-- ,[Follow Up Type Code]
--  ,[Follow Up Type]
--  ,[Referral Given]
--  ,[ReferredToOrgKey]
--  ,[Referred To]
--   ,[Date Added]
--   ,[Added By]
--   ,[Date Modified]
--  ,[Modified By]
--  ,[DivisionKey]
--  ,[EOCAdmissionReasonKey]
--  ,[EOCDischargeReasonKey]
--  ,[EOCFollowupTypeKey]
--  ,[ReferralSourceTypeKey]
--case when convert(DATE, Discharge Date) is Null then '' End as [DC Date]  

FROM [Data_Central].[CIMOR].[EpisodeOfCare]
Where [Facility Code] in ('005','009','026')
and [Discharge Reason] like '%Null%'
```

Comment: Unless you have a string which contains the actual value `'Null'` (which is unlikely), the proper way to compare to `NULL` is `IS NULL`

Comment: Also, your question title doesn't seem to match with what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use IS NULL -

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM [Data_Central].[CIMOR].[EpisodeOfCare]
Where 
     [Facility Code] in ('005','009','026') 
     and ([Discharge Reason] IS NULL OR [DATE] IS NULL)
```